# how to replace imported modules as stub

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I would like to replace imported modules as stub so as to focus on unit testing only the main module. I've tried using sinon.stub but it seems it's not doing what I expect it to do as I keep on getting an error when running the test.

```
    { Error: Command failed: identify: unable to open image `test.exe': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2724.
    identify: no decode delegate for this image format `EXE' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.

        at ChildProcess. (/node_modules/imagemagick/imagemagick.js:88:15)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5) timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

Here is my main module.

```
    // src/services/identifyService.js
    import imagemagick from 'imagemagick';

    class IdentifyService {
        async identify(filePath) {
            imagemagick.identify(['-format', '%w_%h', filePath], function(err, output) {
                if (err) reject(err);

                return resolve(output);
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is my test.

```
    // test/identifyService.test.js
    import imagemagick from 'imagemagick';
    import IdentifyService from '../src/services/identifyService';

    describe('Verify image processing', () => {
        before(() => {
            const fileInfo = [{page: 1, width:100, height: 100, colorspace: 'RGB'}];
            sinon.stub(imagemagick, 'identify').returns(fileInfo);
        });

        it('returns metadata', (done) => {
            const metadata = IdentifyService.identify('test.exe');
            expect(metadata).to.have.lengthOf(0);
        });
    });
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I spotted a problem with the `IdentifyService` class regarding `promise` usage.

```
class IdentifyService {
  identify(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // create a new promise
      imagemagick.identify(['-format', '%w_%h', filePath], function (err, output) {
        if (err) reject(err);

        resolve(output); // no need to specify `return`
      });
    });
  }
}
```

For the test itself, it must use `yields` for `imagemagick.identify` because it is a function with `callback`.

```
describe('Verify image processing', () => {
    before(() => {
        const fileInfo = [{page: 1, width:100, height: 100, colorspace: 'RGB'}];
        sinon.stub(imagemagick, 'identify').yields(null, fileInfo); // use yields
    });    

    it('returns metadata', async () => {
        const metadata = await IdentifyService.identify('test.exe');
        expect(metadata).to.have.lengthOf(0);
    });
});
```

I assume that your environment has support `async await`.